# Use static values within a child class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a class that has the following syntax:-

```
public class CorporateTeamTimeSheetTotalsForSpecifiedTimeFrame
{
    private List<EmployeeMini> _EmployeesList = new List<EmployeeMini>();
    private List<HolidayCalendar> _Holidays = new List<HolidayCalendar>();

    public List<EmployeeMini> EmployeeList
    {
        get { return _EmployeesList; }
        set { _EmployeesList = value; }
    }
}
```

Now I want to access these holidays in individual employee mini i.e. for individual employee.

How can i do that?

Regards
Abhishek

Comment: I see no relation between employees and holidays here. You missed something or I don't get what you're really asking about.

Comment: I would create a separate static class with read only list<holidays> and access wherever required.

Comment: Your EmployeeMini class would have to have a HolidayCalendar property defined so that you could access it for that individual employee. If I have understood correctly what you are getting at.

Comment: @JaroslawWaliszko The data of holidays would be same for all employees. It is defined as the holidays an employee would get in a particular year. That is the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

This code clearly does not show any relationship between `Employees` and `Holidays`. You may simplify this further by associating each `EmployeeMini` with `HolidaysList` and then creating a list of `EmployeeMini`, as:

```
public class EmployeeMini
{
    // ...
    private List<HolidayCalendar> _Holidays = new List<HolidayCalendar>();
    // ...
}

public class CorporateTeamTimeSheetTotalsForSpecifiedTimeFrame
{
    private List<EmployeeMini> _EmployeesList = new List<EmployeeMini>();

    public List<EmployeeMini> EmployeeList
    {
        get { return _EmployeesList; }
        set { _EmployeesList = value; }
    }
}
```

Assuming `_Holidays` is a list of employee holidays and not company holidays.

> Please take this solution as a starting point and not as a copy-paste solution.

---

### Edit:

If data of holidays is same for all employees, you may create a separate entity `Holidays`. You do not have to associate this with the employees. This seems to be a `TimeSheet` application.

You may associate `time entries` with `Employees`, `Tasks` (which is generally the case) and `Holidays`.

Comment: how do i put the holidays when filling up the employee data in the dataaccess layer method.
The data of holidays would be same for all employees.

Comment: Check my edit. Please provide more information about what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Yeah it is a time sheet application.
I have holidays as a separate class, time sheets as a separate class and working days as a separate class. So how to associate employees with the holidays?

Comment: IMO, you should associate `WorkingDays` and `Holidays` with `TimeSheets` and `TimeSheets` with `Employees`. This would help you get association between `Employees` and `Holidays`.

Comment: Hi @Abhishek, were you able to get the structure right? Did this approach work for you?